# SQL 2008r2 : The database is not accessible

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, errors

Is there something that I am missing?

Newly created database with 2 users. Both have the same  permissions.  SQL01 gets error  "The database DB01 is not accessible" on browsing through SSMS.

No login failures in SQL errorlog. 
No user error message thrown in a profiler trace.
user's default database is set to master
SQL01 can access other database on the same instance.

[image: ssms error]

USE DB01;
--throws error

> The server principal "DOM\SQL1" is not able to access the database
> "DB01" under the current security context.

Comment: What is the additional error info from the "show details" link? What error do you get when you execute `USE DB01;` from a query window?

Comment: Don't have the additional info from "show details". USE DB01; throws 'The server principal "DOM\SQL1" is not able to access the database "DB01" under the current security context.'

Comment: Add the script you ran to list permissions to your question. There may be a DENY involved where `DOM\SQL1` is a member of a Windows group that `DOM\SQL2` is not.

Comment: This is the script i used https://github.com/sqlstudent144/SQL-Server-Scripts/blob/master/sp_DBPermissions.sql. Went though all the groups DOM\SQL1 is part of, Couldn't find a DENY.  SQL01 and SQL02 are the only 2 users in the database. It is also a blank new database.

Comment: Can you try a minimal script to reproduce the issue? `CREATE DATABASE Test; GO USE Test: CREATE USER [DOM\SQL1]; CREATE USER [DOM\SQL2]; GO`